# PostgreSQL trigger always shows last modified by "postgres", even the connection in QGIS is with different user

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I've created a role "designer" and assigned it to user: test

```
CREATE USER test_user PASSWORD 'test';
GRANT designer to test_user;
```

then I granted usage of the schema to the role:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA ftth TO designer;
```

After this with the Grant Wizard I've granted Select/Insert/Update/Delete/Execute on all tables/functions/triggers/sequences/project:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION ftth.geometry_function_chambers() TO designer WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION ftth.geometry_function_duct() TO designer WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION ftth.geometry_function_poles() TO designer WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT ALL ON SEQUENCE ftth."Boundaries_id_seq" TO designer WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT ALL ON SEQUENCE ftth."Chambers_id_seq" TO designer WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT ALL ON SEQUENCE ftth."Customer Buildings_id_seq" TO designer WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT ALL ON SEQUENCE ftth."Expensive Drop Buildings_id_seq" TO designer WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT ALL ON SEQUENCE ftth."Fibre Drop_id_seq" TO designer WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT ALL ON SEQUENCE ftth."Fibre Duct_id_seq" TO designer WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT ALL ON SEQUENCE ftth."Fibre Sheath_id_seq" TO designer WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT ALL ON SEQUENCE ftth."Fibre Slack_id_seq" TO designer WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT ALL ON SEQUENCE ftth."National_Heritage_TEMP_id_seq" TO designer WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT ALL ON SEQUENCE ftth."OLT_id_seq" TO designer WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT ALL ON SEQUENCE ftth."Pole_id_seq" TO designer WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT ALL ON SEQUENCE ftth."SED_id_seq" TO designer WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT ALL ON SEQUENCE ftth."Span_id_seq" TO designer WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT ALL ON SEQUENCE ftth."Special_Area_of_Conservation_TEMP_id_seq" TO designer WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT ALL ON SEQUENCE ftth."Special_Protected_Areas_TEMP_id_seq" TO designer WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT ALL ON SEQUENCE ftth."Splice Closures_id_seq" TO designer WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, TRIGGER ON TABLE ftth."Boundaries" TO designer WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, TRIGGER ON TABLE ftth."Chambers" TO designer WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, TRIGGER ON TABLE ftth."Customer Buildings" TO designer WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, TRIGGER ON TABLE ftth."Expensive Drop Buildings" TO designer WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, TRIGGER ON TABLE ftth."Fibre Drop" TO designer WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, TRIGGER ON TABLE ftth."Fibre Duct" TO designer WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, TRIGGER ON TABLE ftth."Fibre Sheath" TO designer WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, TRIGGER ON TABLE ftth."Fibre Slack" TO designer WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, TRIGGER ON TABLE ftth."National_Heritage_TEMP" TO designer WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, TRIGGER ON TABLE ftth."OLT" TO designer WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, TRIGGER ON TABLE ftth."Pole" TO designer WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, TRIGGER ON TABLE ftth."SED" TO designer WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, TRIGGER ON TABLE ftth."Span" TO designer WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, TRIGGER ON TABLE ftth."Special_Area_of_Conservation_TEMP" TO designer WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, TRIGGER ON TABLE ftth."Special_Protected_Areas_TEMP" TO designer WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, TRIGGER ON TABLE ftth."Splice Closures" TO designer WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, TRIGGER ON TABLE ftth."Tree Trimming" TO designer WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, TRIGGER ON TABLE ftth.qgis_projects TO designer WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

When I tried to insert something in QGIS, it always shows me that the table is modified by "postgres".
[image]

Here are the function and the trigger:

```
CREATE FUNCTION "ftth".geometry_function_chambers() RETURNS trigger AS 

$$

BEGIN 

NEW.north = st_y(st_centroid(NEW.geom)); 
NEW.east =st_x(st_centroid(NEW.geom));
NEW.wkt =ST_AsText(st_centroid(NEW.geom));
NEW.exchange = (SELECT name FROM public.eircom_exchange WHERE ST_Within(st_centroid(NEW.geom),geom));
NEW.ch_area = (SELECT area FROM public.areas WHERE ST_Within(st_centroid(NEW.geom),geom));
NEW.ribbon = (SELECT name FROM "ftth"."Boundaries" WHERE LEVEL =4 AND ST_Within(st_centroid(NEW.geom),geom));

NEW.date_modified = now(); 
NEW.modified_by = session_user; 

 RETURN NEW; 
END;

$$language plpgsql;
CREATE TRIGGER update_geometry_chambers
 BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
 ON "ftth"."Chambers"
 FOR EACH ROW
 EXECUTE PROCEDURE "ftth".geometry_function_chambers();
```

I tried to switch different function for the NEW.modified_by as: user and "current_user"() but the output was always same.

I want to create additional accounts under the role designer, and when someone updates in the table I want to see the username of the user that he uses to connect to the PostGIS database.

I was checking the documentation here, but still no success.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-info.html

Comment: So you think `user1` is connecting to the DB, but in fact it is user `postgres`. Forget about the privileges for now and try to find why/how the wrong user is establishing the connection. I would start by re-re-re-looking at the connection details in QGIS, then I would investigate alternative ways of providing the credentials (pgpass, pgservice) or even how postgres is configured to accept (or ignore!) credentials (pg_hba.conf, especially for `TRUST` entries)

Comment: read more details in the [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html)

Comment: I cannot see any additional option on the QGIS side.  https://ibb.co/RHMZccW